# Console app using Console logger will not write final messages. Easy repro

Tags: .net-core, logging, flush

.net 6 console app on Windows using LoggerFactory -  Final messages do not appear on the console.  loggerFactory.Dispose() doesn't help. Ilogger does not have a Dispose() method.

Here's  a repro. About 20 to 70 of the loop messages appear.  After that, nothing.

```
using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
{
    builder
        .AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning)
        .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning)
        .AddFilter("MyTestApp.Program", LogLevel.Debug)
        .AddConsole();
});
ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
try
{ 
    logger.LogInformation("Starting");
    for (var i=0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"This is a nice long message for {i}.");
    }
    throw new Exception("boom");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    logger.LogInformation(e.ToString());
}
finally
{
    loggerFactory.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I see that I can limit the queue length, in which case I do get all the output, but a) why do I have to do this? and b) I might still lose one message, right? ``.AddConsole(configure => { configure.MaxQueueLength = 1; });``

Comment: I also found doc that says that .Log() (Instead of .LogInformation(0), etc). is synchronous.  And yet it still fails to write all messages.  Of course a synchronous method does not mean that the message is not queued: there apparently is still a background writer . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging-providers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's due to the way `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console\src\ConsoleLoggerProcessor.cs` was refactored in [this commit](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commit/bb17fb55c96ed45a6323ded2b88f8b432694840d) ([Associated PR](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/70186)).

Calling `logger.Log` doesn't have to immediately flush the message. If it did, the call could possibly take a long time and block longer than desired. The logger passes the message to all the internal `ILoggers` created from your `ILoggerProvider`s and do what they will with those messages. Configuring LoggerFactory with `builder.AddConsole();` adds `ConsoleLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider` in your situation.

Upon creating an `ILoggerFactory`, all of your configured providers are instantiated and this is when `ConsoleLoggerProvider` [constructs a new class](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/9c818a3176c8505af9ac374ad3369c5832328013/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/src/ConsoleLoggerProvider.cs#L58) called `ConsoleLoggerProcessor`. It's responsible for writing messages to `Console.Out` from a [background thread it creates](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/9c818a3176c8505af9ac374ad3369c5832328013/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/src/ConsoleLoggerProcessor.cs#L71-L76) to process the console logger message queue. Loggers push messages to this queue so they can return to the caller quickly and not block for file IO.

When `ILoggerFactory` is disposed, it will dispose of all created `ILoggerProviders` which results in the disposal of `ConsoleLoggerProcesser`. Disposing *that* class calls `Thread.Join` on the message queue processing thread linked above.

Previously, `ConsoleLoggerProcessor`'s queue was implemented with `BlockingCollection<T>`. Here's an extremely simplified view:

```cs
public class ConsoleLoggerProcessor : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Thread _outputThread;
    private readonly BlockingCollection<string> _messageQueue = new();

    public ConsoleLoggerProcessor()
    {
        _outputThread = new Thread(ProcessLogQueue) { IsBackground = true };
        _outputThread.Start();
    }

    public void EnqueueMessage(string message)
    { /* snip */ }

    private void ProcessLogQueue()
    {
        foreach (var message in _messageQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _messageQueue.CompleteAdding();
        _outputThread.Join(millisecondsTimeout: 1500);
    }
}
```

Upon disposal, the `BlockingCollection` is completed which prevents more adding, **but** `_messageQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable()` does not `yield break;` until **both** conditions are true

- Is adding complete?
- Is the queue empty?

This means that `_outputThread` will not terminate until either `ProcessLogQueue` returns or the `1500` millisecond timeout hits.

Compare this to the new implementation using `Queue<T>`. Again extremely simplified to get the point across.

```cs
public class ConsoleLoggerProcessor : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Thread _outputThread;
    private readonly Queue<string> _messageQueue = new();
    private bool _isAddingCompleted;

    public ConsoleLoggerProcessor()
    {
        _outputThread = new Thread(ProcessLogQueue) { IsBackground = true };
        _outputThread.Start();
    }

    public void EnqueueMessage(string message)
    { /* snip */ }

    private void ProcessLogQueue()
    {
        while (_isAddingCompleted)
        {
            if (_messageQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(_messageQueue.Dequeue());
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _isAddingCompleted = true;
        _outputThread.Join(millisecondsTimeout: 1500);
    }
}
```

When this implementation is disposed, the flag `_isAddingCompleted` is set to `true` and the tight loop in `ProcessLogQueue` essentially terminates immediately. In the real implementation, there are some synchronization barriers so `ProcessLogQueue` doesn't pin a core at 100%.

So it boils down to this:

The previous logger had up to 1.5 seconds to flush what is left in the queue. Blocking your application from exiting for up to 1.5 seconds because `Thread.Join` blocks the calling thread (the main thread) until it terminates.

The current implementation doesn't wait for messages to be flushed. It exits immediately.

Comment: I see that an issue has been created: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/79812

Comment: Good find. I added a comment there with my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the package version issue.

For testing purpose, I crated a .net 6 console application, used your code and reproduced the same issue. The version of  package ***"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging"***, ***"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console"*** and ***"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration"*** are ***7.0.0.***

Then I changed the version to 6.0.0 and everything works well:
[image]

I did another test that making a .net 7 console application with 7.0.0 package. The issue happened again. So I think there's maybe something wrong with package version 7.0.0.

Comment: good finding.  @Hank provided a more detailed response so he gets the bonus, but thanks for responding.